# Filsystem -- folder under folder under folder ...

Tags: php, filesystems, directory

[image: a busy cat]

Hi,

when I click the folder that is in the first folder it just can't recognize what's in it. 
What is it I'm doing wrong ?

```
<?php



 $fil = new SplFileObject(__FILE__);


$dato = new DateTime();
$dato->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen'));
$dato->setTimestamp($fil->getMTime()); // getMTime sidst modificeret

if($_GET) {
$path = $fil->getPath();
$path = $path . "/" . $_GET['mappe'];
} else {
$path = $fil->getPath();
}


$mappeinterator = new FilesystemIterator($path);

foreach ($mappeinterator as $fileinfo) {

   $type = $fileinfo->isDir();
   if(!$type){


echo '<div style="width: 648px; margin:0 auto;">';
echo '<div id="name">';
echo $fileinfo->getFilename();
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="kb">';
echo $fileinfo->getSize() . ' kb' . '<br>';
echo '</div>';


echo '<div id="mo">';
echo 'Modified on';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="m">';
$modificeret = $dato->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
echo $modificeret . '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '</div><br><br>';

} else {



echo '<div style="width: 648px; margin:0 auto;">';
echo '<div id="name">';


//    ------------------------------------------------------
$m = $fileinfo->getFilename();
echo '<a href=op02.php?mappe=' . $m . '>'; 
echo $m;
echo '</a>';
echo '</div>';
 //    ------------------------------------------------------

echo '<div id="kb">';
echo $fileinfo->getSize() . ' kb' . '<br>';
echo '</div>';


echo '<div id="mo">';
echo 'Modified on';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div id="m">';
$modificeret = $dato->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
echo $modificeret . '<br>';
echo '</div>';

echo '</div><br><br>';
}

   }


?>
```

I have more folder in each folder just for the test.
But as you can see it does go further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the directory of `__FILE__` as base. You have to provide the whole path to your sub-subdir that means including MAPPE. Your directory is not C:\xampp\htdocs\AW\Filsystem\mappe3 but C:\xampp\htdocs\AW\Filsystem\MAPPE\mappe3. Therefore you should include the whole relative path in your link:

```
$m = substr($path."\\".$fileinfo->getFilename(), strlen(dirname(__FILE__))+1);
echo '<a href=op02.php?mappe=' . $m . '>';
```

But beware: using request vars for building a path could be a security problem.

Comment: thanx for reply, but now it does not go any where not even into the first folder

Comment: I tried to echo $m but with no luck,

 echo $m;
 echo $path;


path

C:\xampp\htdocs\AW\Filsystem